# $D$ point on a $(D-2)$-flat

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have $D$  points in $D$ dimension, they lie on the same $D-2$-flat, and we associate each point a hyperplane that across through the origin.

For example, in three dimensional case, three data points $x_1,x_2,x_3$ lie on a line, and their corresponding vector is $v_1,v_2,v_3.$ Their corresponding hyperplane is $v_1\cdot x=0,v_2\cdot x=0, v_3\cdot x=0.$ ($v_i\cdot x$ means the inner product).

If $D$ points lie on a $D-2$-flat, how their corresponding hyperplanes related to each other.

Comment: So the hyperplanes associated with the points are not just any hyperplane, but the hyperplanes orthogonal to the points as vectors?

Comment: It seems to depend on whether the $D-2$ flat contains $0.$

Comment: the hyperplanes associated with the points are orthogonal to the points as vector, the D-2 flat do not contains 0